# Can't load Jquery UI script in SharePoint?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sharepoint

I have the JQUERY UI script located in a document library, but it doesn't seem to work when I reference it in a Content Editor WP. However, if I use a public URL it works.

Ex: `script src="/Style%20Library/Scripts/Jquery.ui.js" type="text/javascript"`
//This doesn't work

`script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"`
//This does

All other script libraries work fine when loaded from the document library, except JQuery UI?

Here is what I have in my CEWP.  Jquery is loaded in the master page so I didn't reference it here.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="/Style%20Library/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Style%20Library/Scripts/jquery.ui.position.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Style%20Library/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Style%20Library/Scripts/date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Style%20Library/Scripts/jquery.dp_calendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Style%20Library/Scripts/jquery.ui.1.10.js"></script>
    <script src="/Style%20Library/Scripts/jquery.SPServices-2013.02a.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: One thing I notice is a capitalization difference... Jquery...

Comment: The name is the same on the script src and doc library.

Comment: Your relative path is certainly wrong. What you set means : "http://your.site.com/Style%20Library/Scripts/Jquery.ui.js". The first "/" means the root folder of your website.

Comment: The path is correct i have verified this. Its just not loading

Comment: Look in developer tools, it does look like it loaded.  However, when I try to call dialog, it says object doesn't support method.  However, the public URL still works.

Comment: If you're using a CEWP, make sure you reference your script in an external .txt file. CEWP's are notorious for stripping out markup they deem unnecessary. If you're on 2013, use a script editor instead.

I've used jquery UI in SP on several occasions so there is no conflict with the core.js libraries in SP.

Comment: I am using a cewp linked to a text file in sp 2013.  I will try using a script editor and see the results.  Thanks.

Comment: Same result when using a script editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, when I downloaded JQuery UI, I didn't check all the checkboxes, so some of the dependencies I needed for the Dialog didn't load.  Make sure you check all checkboxes :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is related to `%20` instead of a space:

```
script src="/Style Library/Scripts/Jquery.ui.js" type="text/javascript"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you access your file, using site base URL and the rest specified in your script tag?

Is that file published?

Comment: Thats not answer, I believe it should be in comment.